# How to configure Wordpress for multiple blogs without using multisite?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I would like to use one Wordpress installation to run multiple blogs, each on their own domain.

I'm not going to use the Wordpress users functionality for visitors, only for admins. Every admin is allowed to edit every blog. In the admin there doesn't need to be separation between the blogs. So it seems to me multisite is overkill.

What I need:
- Every blog on own domain
- Separation of blog posts and one "recent posts" page per blog
- Language configurable per blog (or per post)
- Each blog its own name and tagline

How can I accomplish this without using multisite?

Comment: You said `doesn't need to be separation between the blogs`, but you also said `Separation of blog posts`. It's confusing. But from what I understand it's not overkill to use multisite for what you want to achieve. There is no simple way to achieve this with single wordpress install.

Comment: You would reinvent Multisite.